# AttributeError: module 'Crypto.Cipher.AES' has no attribute 'block_size'

Tags: python, aes

I am trying AES encryption with python 3.

I have executed the below code and getting the following error:

**AttributeError: module 'Crypto.Cipher.AES' has no attribute 'block_size'**

I have surfed and searched on Google a lot but no solution founded.

Can anyone help please?

```
from hashlib import md5
from base64 import b64decode
from base64 import b64encode

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad


class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = md5(key.encode('utf8')).digest()

    def encrypt(self, data):
        iv = get_random_bytes(AES.block_size)
        self.cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return b64encode(iv + self.cipher.encrypt(pad(data.encode('utf-8'),
            AES.block_size)))

    def decrypt(self, data):
        raw = b64decode(data)
        self.cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, raw[:AES.block_size])
        return unpad(self.cipher.decrypt(raw[AES.block_size:]), AES.block_size)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('TESTING ENCRYPTION')
    msg = input('Message...: ')
    pwd = input('Password..: ')
    print('Ciphertext:', AESCipher(pwd).encrypt(msg).decode('utf-8'))

    print('\nTESTING DECRYPTION')
    cte = input('Ciphertext: ')
    pwd = input('Password..: ')
    print('Message...:', AESCipher(pwd).decrypt(cte).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: What version of PyCrypto you have? Current has `block_size` in AES module (proof [1](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html#block_size) and [2](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py#L205))

Comment: @crissal which version should I use?

Comment: I am currently using PyCryptodome

Comment: @topaco I have tried the Sandbox code and its still showing me the error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue online with _PyCryptodome_ 3.8.2 (May 2019) or locally with 3.9.8 (June 2020), the current version is 3.10.1 (Feb 2021). Probably this is a local problem of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I just used 16 as a block size instead of trying to solve the actual problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).